# How to add button to Gutenberg Editing Toolbar in Wordress

Tags: block-editor

I'm looking any solutions how to add custom button to top toolbar in Gutenberg editor. I want to add button like "Design Library" in Kadence Blocks plugin. As far as I know there is no official way for that, but Kadence did it somehow.

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s [how Kadence does it](https://github.com/stellarwp/kadence-blocks/blob/ab31b4a1c225b90c7fc524845b826cae9b08e256/src/plugins/prebuilt-library/toolbar-library.js). I'd avoid hacks like that if possible but I'm not sure what your requirements are.

Some alternative ideas (not mutually exclusive):

- Use [plugin sidebar](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/plugin-sidebar-0/)
- Add [a command](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/07/17/introducing-the-wordpress-command-palette-api/) to do whatever the button would
- Add a keyboard shortcut to do whatever the button would

On that third item I don't know of a good documentation example of how to do it but here’s the [relevant parts in core of how it's done for the Keyboard Shortcut Help modal](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AWordPress%2Fgutenberg%20edit-post%2Fkeyboard-shortcuts&type=code). It's a two-step of `registerShortcut`/`useShortcut`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this!